# Software to securely delete free HDD space

Tags: cleaner

So, I am looking to rewrite the free space of an HDD, making any file delete normally before that unrecoverable. It seems several software do this. There is BleachBit but according to [this](https://www.bleachbit.org/forum/wipe-free-space-windows-10), it doesn't delete the MFT. Then there is CCleaner, but it's kinda infamous.
What would be a good software for this?

Comment: If you only want to make files unrecoverable, it does not matter if the Master File Table is overwritten, it only holds metadata. That said, anything that can create files containing random or null data can be used to fill up your empty space, that's basically what BleachBit & Co do anyway. Create a new file container with TrueCrypt e.g. and copy it until your disk is full, then delete.

Comment: While such software exists, I feel it is dangerous to rely on it - wiping individual files is very tricky for a number of reasons. See my answer on SuperUser:  [FOSS Wipe free space (7, 35 passes)](https://superuser.com/questions/157931/foss-wipe-free-space-7-35-passes/158035#158035).